# PHP only wrapping first search result in DIV

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So in my search.php it will gives results. I want each of those results to be wrapped in a div class so that I can edit them all and display them like long cards. However currently my code is only wrapping the first DIV. Can't really figure out why that is since the code loops per result right and should rewrap the next result in a DIV? Well here's my code and page of search results.

Search Site I'm testing this on: [This will take you straight to the search result page](http://chocobento.x10.mx/wp/?s)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="content" role="main">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<header class="header">
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'blankslate' ), get_search_query() ); ?></h1>
</header>
<div class="item"><?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" >'; the_post_thumbnail('medium'); echo '</a>';?>

<?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'nav', 'below' ); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
<header class="header">
<h2 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'blankslate' ); ?></h2>
</header>
<section class="entry-content">
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing matched your search. Please try again.', 'blankslate' ); ?></p>
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
</section>
</article>
<?php endif; ?>
</section>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Your `<div class="item">` is out of the loop...

Comment: move "<div class="item"> inside the while loop

Comment: thank you both, how did I not catch that? Total facepalm moment. Thanks a lot guys

Comment: You didn't spot it because your code is structured badly. Use indentation to make stuff readable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outputting your first `<div>` element outside the loop, and the close `</div>` element inside the loop. Move your first  inside the `while` loop to have it correct.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="item">
    <?php echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" >'; the_post_thumbnail('medium'); echo '</a>';?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Can i just add to this answer (which is correct), that the main area the current code goes wrong is in it's **readability**. If the op had structured his code like Mike here has, he would've spotted the problem straight away.

Comment: Thanks! I'm fairly new to this but I can't believe I didn't catch that!
I'll mark yours as the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @DrunkWolf Yea.. I'm sorry guys I was rushing cause its pass 1 AM and just goes to show never use anything as an excuse for sloppy code. Mega face palm.

Comment: @コードバ リノ Hey we've all been there, especially in the beginning we tend to break the rules/conventions or flat out disagree with them. Only with time and experience we start seeing the value and reasoning behind conventions.

Comment: @DrunkWolf Thanks for such kind words it's my first major WordPress Project and first time diving head first into PHP as well. But this community has been so great literally brings a tear of joy in my eye :3.. what I mainly love is that not only do they help solve the issue but explain why it was wrong... GOSH I LOVE STACKOVERFLOW!